# Kubernetes Encryption Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-secrets

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/
According to the above document in order to use encryption configuration, we need to edit the `kube-apiserver.yaml` file. But in GCP, Azure or AWS we cannot view this the api-server as it is managed by the cloud provider. How can we use encryption configuration in this case? Has anyone managed to use encryption configuration to encrypt secrets in GCP,Azure and AWS?

Comment: It can be done, which cloud provider you are using?

Comment: Need a solution for all three clouds.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Secret Manager(GSM)](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)is GCP’s flagship service for storing, rotation and retrieving secrets. A secret in GSM could be stored in encrypted form. It supports IAM for authentication and fine grained access controls

[Azure Key Vault FlexVolume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/developer-best-practices-pod-security?WT.mc_id=docs-azuredevtips-azureappsdev) and for aws Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes (EKS) are the other tools that can be used